# Linux Host: Background Jobs + VM + Prioritization?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vmware-workstation, nice

I'm running a setup consisting of a Linux host OS and a Windows 7 guest (VMware Workstation).  I'm trying to run 16 CPU-bound background jobs on the Linux host at nice values of 19 (the lowest possible priority; one for each virtual CPU) and simultaneously use the Windows VM as a normal desktop OS.  For some reason the Linux background jobs make my Windows VM grind to a halt even though VMware's nice value is 0.

If it helps, I'm running an 8-core machine with hyperthreading, so 16 virtual CPUs.  Since VMware Workstation only supports virtualizing 8 cores, only 8 of the cores are visible in the Windows guest.

Edit:  The background jobs I'm running are almost purely CPU bound and perform virtually no I/O.

Edit # 2:  It's not an issue with hyperthreading messing up scheduling.  Disabling hyperthreading in the BIOS solves nothing.

Comment: -20 is the highest priority, and don't forget you have a bunch of linux processes running in the background already, besides your jobs.

Comment: @Spencer:  Right, but AFAIK 0 is the highest priority for user processes.

Comment: Another thing to look at would be if vmware uses a multiprocess architecture. That is, you have a central daemon process, and separate vm processes. I'm not familiar enough to know if that would be an issue. Or it could just be a settings issue in the vm setup. I know that I've run into that with virtual box. If you don't set it to allow 3d graphics acceleration, it runs like a dog with anything more than a feather weight graphical os, especially windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether it is really CPU or rather I/O that slowes your system. `vmstat 1` might be a good idea, and maybe `top`. The 19 processes are supposed to **do something**, right?

Rememer that a desktop hdd can not take more than ~100 random I/Os per second. Nice'd processes should get less I/O, but so many of them will still get enough.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was going on here.  The jobs I was running were dumping a bunch of output I didn't care about to /dev/null.  Running other jobs in the background that really are purely CPU bound works fine.